# JSF and PrimeFaces Strategy

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**What is or could be a best practice?**

1. Using standard **JSF** components and combine them by *PrimeFaces* components when needed (for example when DHTML or AJAX components are needed)
2. Forget all **JSF** Components and try to use all *PrimeFaces* components as much as possible

Please explain it and tell me about your experiences.

***Thanks in advance...***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PrimeFaces is your AJAX framework, so if you need to send ajaxical request, then use PrimeFaces components.

Even though, you dont need to send ajax request, but you can still use PF component, if u need to provide a consistency look for your web page. For example, `h:commandButton` and `p:commandButton`. Use `p:commandButton` if u need to send ajax request, but u can also do this

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="Your Action here"/>
```

This will provide the same result as:

```
<h:commandButton action="Your Action here"/>
```

but this way, you can provide the same consistent look for your button throughout the page.

PrimeFaces does not have replacements for `h:panelGrid`, `h:panelGroup`, `h:inputText`, `h:outputText` ...

Comment: PF 3.0 has p:outputText, p:inputText :)

Comment: @selvin: PF3.0 M1 has not even released yet. It will take couples months for the stable release to come out. You can try the nightly build, but that mainly for testing and playing around. I would not recommended using it for your current working project.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the sole functional requirement. If you're already using PrimeFaces and whatever you want to achieve can better/easier be achieved using a PrimeFaces component, use it.

Option 1 comes close, but option 2 goes overboard. PrimeFaces for example doesn't have a `<p:form>`, `<p:panelGroup>`, `<p:outputText>` or something.

Answer (score 3):

With Primefaces it's very easy to get a consistent look for your application since it comes with Themeroller CSS framework. And you can easily switch designs. Although it is not difficult to let plain jsf components look like primefaces components if you apply the right css classes.

I think primefaces is a great component library. However some components are still buggy (e.g. date picker). So if you get some unexpected behavior with a primefaces component, it is alway good to have a jsf fallback (or an alternative from another component library or from jquery).

I have no experience with mixing different component libraries. Would be interesting to know, how they interact. But that would be subject of another question ...